# Pandas to_csv does not accept path on windows

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I run Python 3.9.5 on Windows 10. `pd.to_csv` does not accept my filename. I tried following filenames:

```
path='C:User/Labor/.../data/'+'myfilename.csv'
path='C:User\\Labor\\...\\data\\'+'myfilename.csv'
path=r'C:User\Labor\...\data\'+'myfilename.csv'
path=os.path.join('C:User\\Labor\\...\\data','myfilename.csv')
```

But I get every time following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Labor\Documents\Jonathan\rgb_spektrometer\Python_functions.py", line 53, in <module>
    append_dataframe(create_file('test'),a,position,wavelength,voltage)
  File "C:\Users\Labor\Documents\Jonathan\rgb_spektrometer\Python_functions.py", line 46, in append_dataframe
    df.to_csv(filename)
  File "C:\Users\Labor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3387, in to_csv
    return DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_csv(
  File "C:\Users\Labor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1083, in to_csv
    csv_formatter.save()
  File "C:\Users\Labor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 228, in save
    with get_handle(
  File "C:\Users\Labor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 558, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "C:\Users\Labor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 333, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    file_obj = fsspec.open(
  File "C:\Users\Labor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\fsspec\core.py", line 134, in open
    out = self.__enter__()
  File "C:\Users\Labor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\fsspec\core.py", line 102, in __enter__
    f = self.fs.open(self.path, mode=mode)
  File "C:\Users\Labor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\fsspec\spec.py", line 942, in open
    f = self._open(
  File "C:\Users\Labor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\fsspec\implementations\local.py", line 120, in _open
    return LocalFileOpener(path, mode, fs=self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Labor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\fsspec\implementations\local.py", line 202, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "C:\Users\Labor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\fsspec\implementations\local.py", line 207, in _open
    self.f = open(self.path, mode=self.mode)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/Labor/Documents/data/test2021-05-26 18:47:37.csv'
```

none of the options i tried seem to work.

Comment: Try using relative paths and `os.path.join`

Comment: `os.path` is always a good idea for dealing with paths, because it automatically figures out which separators to use depending on your operating system. Like that you don't have to bother with `\\`, `/`, etc.

Comment: os.path.join doeas not work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% certain on this but about 95%... you have spaces in the file name.

```
test2021-05-26 18:47:37.csv
```

That's probably the heart of your problem right there. It's trying to read the file as if the info after the space were arguments, also ":" in a file name can cause some problems too.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Traceback you posted, `create_file('test')` in `Python_functions.py` passes to `df.to_csv(filename)` the filename 'C:/Users/Labor/Documents/data/test2021-05-26 18:47:37.csv', which is incorrect (you can't have colon ':' in a filename).

Try modifying the definition of `create_file` so that it replaces colon with underscores before calling `to_csv`, something like this: `filename.replace(":", "_")`.

Comment: How could I choose a certain file path on a device without 'C:/'? Replacing ':' with '_' is no option.

Comment: The file path is copied from the file explorer, so it should be correct.

Comment: File name and file path are two different things. If `filename` is indeed the file path, you should consider choosing a different name, such as `path_to_file`.